# How does the update operation work in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm new to Yii framework. I created a table `TblUser`. Now, I have three columns `username`,`password` and `email`.
I'm using `CRUD` operations in Yii. Connection to database is successfully made. I was able to create a new record in the table also.
Now the entry in the database reads as

```
+----+----------+----------+--------------------+
| id | username | password | email              |
+----+----------+----------+--------------------+
|  1 | test1    | pass1    | test1@example.com  |
|  2 | test2    | pass2    | test2@example.com  |
|  3 | test3    | pass3    | test3@example.com  |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

**Now, in the view form I removed the field `email` by commenting (_form.php). I'm using this form to update the remaining fields.**

```
 <?php
    /* @var $this TblUserController */
    /* @var $model TblUser */
    /* @var $form CActiveForm */
    ?>

    <div class="form">

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'tbl-user-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    )); ?>

            <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

            <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

            <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
            </div>
<!--    
            <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
            </div>
-->    
            <div class="row buttons">
                    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
            </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

To use rest of the fields I commented the `email` field in the _form.php. 
Now in my controller I have the update code as shown below :

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
        {
                $model=$this->loadModel($id);

                // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
                // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

                if(isset($_POST['TblUser']))
                {
                        $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUser'];
                        if($model->save())
                                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                }

                $this->render('update',array(
                        'model'=>$model,
                ));
        }
```

When I see my query logs, the query updated is

```
UPDATE `tbl_user` SET `id`=2, `username`='1234', `password`='1234', `email`='test2@example.com' WHERE `tbl_user`.`id`=2
```

and not

```
UPDATE `tbl_user` SET `password`='1234' WHERE `tbl_user`.`id`=2
```

**Now my question why is updating the unchanged values again instead of updating only changed values.** Does Yii do this update query for everything. How does this work.

Comment: If you look at the model associated with this you will likely still have this field referenced, you may need to remove the field from the database and regenerate the model using gii. Obviously backing up any modifications. A well formed question by the way, kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yii, New record save and updating existing records are similar actions.

While saving new record, object will be created as below.

```
$model = new User;
```

Now every  model have flag called `isNewRecord`. This will be set to `false`/0.
For edit/update

```
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
```

Now `isNewRecord` will be `true`/1

Based on the flag, Insert or Update query will be executed.

Yii doesn't know which are fields changed. So it;s just updating all the fields values related with model (i.e table) based on the flag.

Comment: From the documents I see that the same save function is used for both insert and update operations. But, will it not differ from the normal update query. My worry is doesn't it affect the record in the database, if it is stored as a new record.

Comment: However your model having already existing values. So It'll not affect the existing unchanegd values. And also it wont inserted as new record while you are updating.

Answer (score 0):

Saving all the fields on a record on update is good practice for databases. Image the scenario of two people editing the same record, at the same time. Person 1 saves his record, and the database only saves his changes. Person two saves his changes, which are different to user 1. The result is a record that doe not fully reflect what either user wanted. To get round this, Yii saves all the values, even unchanged ones. This way, at least one user will be happy!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only update certain columns you can do that with the `update()` function instead of the `save()` function. Example:

```
$model->update(array('password'));
```

Yii doesn't auto-detect which columns have been modified so you have to keep track if you only want to update columns that have been changed. But in the case of an update password form or update status or something like that why you would use `update()` instead of `save()` since you know only one field is being changed.

For reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#update-detail